# tr:nth-child css zebra striping after xml jquery parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

How do I apply styling to a table after parsing XML data into the table?
In the code below I Created the first three rows of a table using html, then the additional rows were created by parsing XML. however the Zebra stripe styling was not applied to the table after the jquery call. I've tried my best to find the problem with my code but I'm stumped.

Here's a code sample of my html:

```
    <head>
    <title>Football Players</title>
    <style>
      table{
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border: solid 1px #dddddd;
          width: 500px;
      }
      th{
          text-align: left;
      }
    </style>

   </head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lionel Messi</td>
        <td>Barcelona</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Argentina</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Juan Mata</td>
        <td>Manchester United</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

And the following is a snippet of my JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "football_player.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: processXML

  });

  function processXML(xml) {
    $(xml).find("football_player").each(function () {
      $("table tbody").append("<tr class = 'myClass'>");
      $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</td>");
      $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("club").text() + "</td>");
      $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("number").text() + "</td>");
      $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("country").text() + "</td>");
      $("table tbody").append("</tr>");           
    });//close processXML


    $("table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
  }     
});//close document.ready()
```

And lastly the XML file:

```
    <football_players>
  <football_player>
    <name>Cristiano Ronaldo</name>
    <club>Real Madrid</club>
    <number>7</number>
    <country>Portugal </country>
  </football_player>

  <football_player>
    <name>Fernando Torres </name>
    <club>Chelsea </club>
    <number>9</number>
    <country>Spain</country>
  </football_player>

  <football_player>
    <name>Iker Casillas</name>
    <club>Real Madrid </club>
    <number>1</number>
    <country>Spain</country>
  </football_player>    

  <football_player>
    <name>David Beckham</name>
    <club>Los Angeles Galaxy</club>
    <number>23</number>
    <country>England</country>
  </football_player>
</football_players>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the console is always a good idea,The problem in your code probably is in the function `processXML(xml)`.This is beacause your `<tr>` were closed before adding `<td>`.Hence it was not applying the color.

Change it to..

```
     function processXML(xml) {
        $(xml).find("football_player").each(function () {
           $("table tbody").append("<tr class = 'myClass'>"+"<td>" +   
$(this).find("name").text() + "</td>"+"<td>" + $(this).find("club").text() + "</td>"+"<td>" + $(this).find("number").text() + "</td>"+"<td>" + $(this).find("country").text() + "</td>"+"</tr>");           
        });//close processXML


 $("table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Varun! Copy and paste of your code didn't work but I edited my code using your guideline and it worked! here it is:

Comment: PS this is my first ever question on Stack Overflow and I look forward to more great experiences like this!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Varun I came up with the following which worked:

```
function processXML(xml) {
    $(xml).find("football_player").each(function () {
      $("table tbody").append("<tr class = 'myClass'><td>" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("club").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("number").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("country").text() + "</td></tr>");           
    });


    $("table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
  }
```